# script to execute on vmware

Tags: bash, shell, vmware, esxi

VMware ESXi systems provide a shell with specific commands like esxcli and works only on those nodes. I want to write a script to read the system IP from a file, login each system and execute the command `esxcli network ip get`.

When I execute the script, that returns "command not found" error:

```
> "./snmp.sh: line 3: esxcli: command not found
```

Is there a way to fix this? The script is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read host; do
  ssh -n root@$host esxcli network ip get
done < esxi.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`exscli` isn't in your PATH on the esxi server. Simplest fix is to use it with its full path (f.e. `/usr/bin/esxcli`). You can find the valid path of the esxcli command on the esxi server with the command `which esxcli`.

Comment: The issue is not with esxcli not installed or path set on esxi server. When I do manual ssh, login to esxi and execute, that works fine.. however not via script.                                                            ~]# ssh root@10.145.7.1
Password:
                                                                              
~ #  /usr/bin/esxcli network ip get
   IPv6Enabled: true
~ #

Comment: @user3331975 No, you will have another PATH, because it will be a noninteractive shell on the esxi side, and some of the initscripts (partially, setting PATH) aren't called. It is really simple to test: try to run _anything_ from a scripted ssh with full path, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can run scripts in ESXI with shell.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "some vms:"
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms
```

And save it as "something.sh".

There are some difference with shell and bash,

Some info [here about shell.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-what-is-shell.htm) and
more info about [the difference here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)